# Transformer location

Tags: wiring, junction-box, transformer

I've got a very basic question - I have a 120V to 24V transformer https://www.functionaldevices.com/products/building-automation/details/TR40VA040/ and on the transformer surface it calls out "install in metal box only". So my understanding is that it's supposed to be screwed into the metal junction box, but the transformer itself is to be located outside of the box, possibly in the wall cavity, like pictured here:

[image]

Is this a correct way of positioning the transformer? Or does "in metal box" mean literally "inside of the metal box"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly right.

The purpose of this arrangement is to put the mains voltage on one side of the "Great Wall Of Separation", and the low voltage on the other, as called out  by the Code requirements for (not) mixing low voltage and mains.

However, as Tyson points out, the junction box must remain accessible and have a cover.  I assume this is unimproved space, or you are putting a box extension on it to raise it to the finished wall surface. Burying the entire junction box and transformer behind drywall, that is no-go.

Comment: P.S. a plastic box with KOs for ENT or PVC should work just as well as a metal box -- the problem with many garden variety plastic boxes is they simply don't have KOs, so you'd have to go through the hassle of putting a KO in yourself, which is possible with a KO holesaw and extreme care, but probably impractical if the box is already in place.

Comment: Almost exactly right, it’s missing wire nuts on hot an neutral and it’s missing a blank cover.  It’s also assumed this will remain accessible from this side and not actually be sealed inside a wall cavity with another surface such as Sheetrock.

Comment: @Tyson -- as long as the box itself is not covered by a building surface, it's OK to seal the device inside the wall cavity

Comment: A 24 V transformer in my house (for the doorbell) is installed on a metal blank cover on a recessed box so the transformer is projecting into the room (a closet containing the a/c air handler evaporator and NG furnace. The walls of the closet are drywall.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel if as the OP states the unit is labeled “metal box only” does it maintain its listings if used with a plastic box?

Comment: @Tyson -- actually, you have a good point, come to think of it, that unit specifically may rely on its primary-side nipple for equipment grounding, so in the absence of a metal j-box, you'd need to use a grounding locknut on the nipple with a ground wire attached to ground it

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel as pictured it does appear to have a green ground wire.  Just no wire nuts on hot and neutral.  But to my original point if something is labeled for use on metal only I think the label needs to be followed.  (Maybe this is just a pic OP found to resemble what he wanted to ask about, and not actually his unit.)

Comment: @Tyson -- I do not believe the unit in the screenshot is actually the unit in question

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I actually assumed it was right up until i was typing the last comment.  Since I’m at the shop I actually walked out and looked at what’s in our stock, the new units have a green ground and no metal box only label, we also have one used transformer that it is stamped metal box only, and does rely on that connection for equipment ground.

Comment: Thanks guys, very helpful. Unit in the picture is a random youtube video, somewhat resembling future installation. I was planning to place the junction box in the wall cavity and cover the whole setup with a removable metal or plastic panel.